# Negative type assertion return predicate

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write two jest functions that expect an object to be an instance of a certain type or not.

The positive example `expectInstanceOf` works like a charm, but the negative one `expectNotInstanceOf` doesn't.

```
export function expectInstanceOf<E, A extends unknown[]>(obj: unknown, type: new (...args: A) => E): asserts obj is E {
  expect(obj).toBeInstanceOf(type);
}

export function expectNotInstanceOf<E, A extends unknown[]>(obj: unknown, type: new (...args: A) => E): asserts obj is Exclude<typeof obj, E> {
  expect(obj).not.toBeInstanceOf(type);
}

class Foo {
  foo() {
    /**/
  }
}
class Bar {
  bar() {
    /**/
  }
}

function foo(obj: Foo | Bar) {
  expectInstanceOf(obj, Foo);
  obj.foo();
}

function notFoo(obj: Foo | Bar) {
  expectNotInstanceOf(obj, Foo);
  obj.bar(); // Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'Foo | Bar'.
}
```

How can I fix `expectNotInstanceOf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `typeof obj` is always [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) (you can't use [the `typeof` type query operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) to "abstract" a specific type), and [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) only filters [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `T`.  `unknown` is not a union, and so `Exclude<unknown, E>` is very likely going to be `unknown` (I suppose it could also be [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) if `E` is `unknown`). So while `expectInstanceOf` narrows to `E`, expectNotInstanceOf`narrows to`unknown`, which isn't helpful.

What you want to do is make `obj` have its own [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter (say, `T`) and then rephrase the narrowing in terms of `T`.  For example:

```
function expectInstanceOf<T, E, A extends unknown[]>(
    obj: T, type: new (...args: A) => E): asserts obj is T & E { }

function expectNotInstanceOf<T, E, A extends unknown[]>(
    obj: T, type: new (...args: A) => E): asserts obj is T & Exclude<T, E> { }
```

Now the example code works as desired:

```
function foo(obj: Foo | Bar) {
    expectInstanceOf(obj, Foo);
    obj.foo(); // okay
}

function notFoo(obj: Foo | Bar) {
    expectNotInstanceOf(obj, Foo);
    obj.bar(); // okay
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAZgrgdgxgLgSwPZQAQFMAeAHd8CSUAznAIazoDyYAPACoA0qAokwIIaZzpQAmRqaAGsoSAO5QA2gF0AfAApQqZaiQAjAFYAuVI1RwAnrh1R0Y1PIB010gCcA5kR1sAlKgC8sli52kiRdFs4AXUNVAQBOlQAMhZUAG9UAF9QSFhEFE5ceAA5JDhCEnIYKlo9VlQOLG4+AWFRCRkFJRVQnT1DY1RTcysbBydKt09vX39A4NVNcMiYlkwYABsIXnR6JmYvRJSQUCW-AQAxJCQEluUwE-k3ePOVZQB6AConh7udnf3-VAAhOzOQPc1HZrgD7vdnq93qAdqloPBkGhLkh5G1UMdTgAfX52G53LDZArEMgUaiozRMDEuADcd1ClmR12pqAeD1UQlIBhhoDh6UR3XyGPJ2nRJ1Q2L+tjxgJUBLwcDyRKKpLAwspJxpdM0lmBtiZLLZSA5XJASSAA)